# What does vector<unsigned char> vchTmp(pend-pbegin+1, 0); mean?

Tags: c++, bitcoin

What does

```
vector<unsigned char> vchTmp(pend-pbegin+1, 0);
```

mean?

This line is taken from the base58.h source code from the first commit of bitcoin source code. [source here](https://github.dev/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/4405b78d6059e536c36974088a8ed4d9f0f29898)

click on base58.h

line 27

I cannot understand what does it mean.

Thanks
Massimo

Comment: That should be the declaration of a vector of unsigned chars initialized to `pend-pbegin+1` elements containing `0` values, see signature (3) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: ... and the `, 0` part is unnecessary.

Comment: @TedLyngmo and fabian, should `0` be `'0'` instead since `0` is an integer but `'0'` is a character literal and the element type is `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Anya It seems to be working bitcoin code, so I guess no. Someone just wanted to be explicit with initialization.

Comment: @Anya It depends on how it's used. `0` could be used as a null terminator while `'0'` is just another character

Comment: @Anya you mean `'\0' `

Comment: @TedLyngmo So will the integer `0` will be converted to an `unsigned char` while initializing the vector. Then, will it be correct to say that the elements are initialized with the character(`char`) corresponding to the character code `0`?

Comment: to the character code 0, which is the NUL character and not '0'

Comment: Ok thank you all for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
inline string EncodeBase58(const unsigned char* pbegin, const unsigned char* pend)
{
    // Convert big endian data to little endian
    // Extra zero at the end make sure bignum will interpret as a positive number
    vector<unsigned char> vchTmp(pend-pbegin+1, 0);
    reverse_copy(pbegin, pend, vchTmp.begin());
    // ...
```

This means that the function takes a *begin* and *end* iterator defined as `const unsigned char*`. It then creates a `vector<unsigned char>` with the size of the distance between `pbegin` and `pend` and adds one extra `unsigned char` (`+1`).

Apparently that is to make *"bignum"* (a library dealing with big numbers) always interpret it as a positive number. The `0` is copied into all `unsigned char` elements in the vector. `0` is the default value here so it's unnecessary.

It would probably be clearer to do:

```
vector<unsigned char> vchTmp(std::distance(pbegin, pend) + 1);
```

The following `reverse_copy` puts the data `[pbegin, pend)` into `vchTmp` in reverse order.

```
reverse_copy(pbegin, pend, vchTmp.begin());
```

If you'd call the function like this:

```
unsigned char arr[] = {'B','a','r'};
EncodeBase58(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Then `vchTmp` would contain 4 elements, in this order: `'r'`, `'a'`, `'B'`, `0` (except they are `unsigned char`, not `char`). The last `0` is the the extra `0` that was added by creating the vector with `+1` above.

Answer (score 1):

The statement creates a `vector` named `vchTmp` with elements of type `unsigned char` and with `pend - pbegin + 1` number of elements. Moreover all of those elements are initialized with the integer `0`.

The statement uses constructor 3 listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
vector( size_type count,
         const T& value,
         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Note that the `char`(and `unsigned char`) data type is an **integral type**, meaning the underlying value is stored as an integer. Now, the integer stored by a `char`(and `unsigned char`) variable is *intepreted* as an **ASCII** character. And since they've specified the integer `0` which corresponds to the **NUL character** `'\0'` in the ASCII table, this **effectively means** that the statement creates a vector named `vchTmp` that contains `pend - pbegin + 1` NUL characters.

For example,

```
unsigned char arr[]   = "stackoverflow";
unsigned char* pbegin = arr;
unsigned char*pend    = arr + 3;
    
std::vector<unsigned char> vchTmp(pend-pbegin+1, 0); //vchTmp contains 4 NUL characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(5, 72);
```

This means ***declaring a std::vector*** named ***vec*** of the type ***unsigned char***, which has ***5 elements***, and ***each of those 5 elements contains the value 72***, which when translated to char (as the type of the vector is unsigned **char**), means ***'H'***. So the values in ***vec*** are:

```
{ 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H' }
```

Thus, the above line of code can also be written as:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(5, 'H');
```

Comment: Where comes the value 10?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 72. Change made.